# Need help with javascript disabling / enabling

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  links_disabled = false;

  $('a').click(function(e){
    links_disabled = (links_disabled ? false : true);
  });
</script>
```

My link:

```
<a href="/board/take_turn?id=131&x=0&y=2" data-remote="true" onclick="return links_disabled;">
  <div class="ttt_square"> 
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</a>
```

What I want to do is when I click a link like the one above, I want it to disable the rest of the links. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Do you want to follow the link, but just disable the rest while it's "loading"?

Comment: Why are you both binding a click handler via jQuery and using the onclick attribute at the same time? It seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: As @David Wolever points out in his answer, `<a>` tags can only contain inline content, but a `<div>` is a block element.

Comment: if u only want to override the clik handle use e.preventDefault();

Comment: @Pointy: [Do you think so?](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/gJEMm/)

Comment: Well, it *might* work, but it's invalid markup. That's the sort of error that can cause weak old browsers to do really weird things.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about old browsers, as they annoy me. I'm aiming for pure webkit / firefox.

Comment: Anyway, so, yeah, I want the link to activate and then disable all the other links.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from putting a `<div>` inside an `<a>`, yes: it looks like you're on the right track.

Of course, you are swapping the `links_disabled` when links are clicked, which might not do what you want…

Answer (score 0):

```
// initialize to false
var links_disabled = false;

// bind to a link click
$('a').click(function(){
  // reverse the value of the disabled variable
  links_disabled = !links_disabled;

  // return the result (no need for it to go in markup as
  // jQuery is already handling this)
  return links_disabled;
});
```

then the HTML

```
<!-- no longer need for onClick, jQuery is already binding to this event -->
<a href="/link/to/file">Some Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/seamusjr/X7Y9w/3/embedded/result/

Basically I put the links in a nav element so they are siblings.
When I click on one it removes the disabled attr and className from itself and applies it to its sibling links.